# Python Email Spammer only sending to one email

Tags: python, email

My Code:

```
print '    '
sender =  raw_input('Attacker Email:   ') 
print '    '

subjcet = raw_input('Subject:    ')
print '    '
password = raw_input('Password:   ') 
print '    '
recipients = raw_input ('Emails,  Multiple with "," :  ')
print '    '
msg = raw_input('Message:  ')

print '    ' +bcolors.OKBLUE



s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)

s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()
s.login(sender, password)


s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg)
  


print "Email sent to: " + recipients
```

I want  it to send one message to all emails given in `recipients = raw_input`

But it's only sending the message to the first email.
any help would be great

Thanks.

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: Yes, I agree. You should also use the python2 tag.

Comment: Ok i now updated my script to python3 (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recipients is a string currently: `"E1, E2, E3"`

You need it to be a list: `["E1", "E2", "E3"]`

Try this:

```
recipients = recipients.split(", ")
```

Comment: Thanks.   It Does work but i get this: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: Which line do you get this error on? Can you provide the full traceback output? Also, by "it does work", do you mean it successfully sent the emails?

Comment: Yes, I mean it sends the emails. The error:  File "emailspammer1.py", line 128, in <module>                                     
    print "Email sent to: " + recipients                                             
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: nevermind, I got it Thanks!! i just did str(recipients)

Comment: Oh, so the program errors out after it sends, but when you try to print the "send successful message". Yes, since recipients is a list (that is the only way to send emails correctly), you cannot join a list and a string. Your approach technically works (with str(recipients), but a nicer way to do this would be iterating through the elements in the list and printing them out one by one.